# Como dividir uma variavel em um array

Tags: php

A minha pergunta é um pouco complexa, pelo qual vou tentar explicar.

Tenho uma variável php, que apresenta sempre resultados da seguinte forma:

```
"8017990310062\r8017990142064\r801792340068\r"
```

O que pretendo fazer é "arrumar" os números apresentados da variavel e atribuir em uma array, ou seja, antes de mais pretendo tirar as aspas da variavel, depois remover os \r e de seguida, pegar nos números e cada array tenha um numero.

Exemplo:

```
$array[0] = 8017990310062;
$array[1] = 8017990142064;
$array[2] = 801792340068;
```

Atenção, que a minha variável pode apresentar mais do que 3 valores, como por exemplo `5`, `7` ou `8`.

Como poderei fazer isto?

Comment: Tenta lá: `explode('\r', $var);` se percebi bem acho que vai dar o que queres. A `$var` é a tua string inteira

Comment: Acho que é isso mesmo, contudo como faço para primeiro remover as "aspas" do resultado da variavel?

Comment: Tens uma resposta já em baixo que faz o que queres Gonçalo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça assim:

```
$var = "8017990310062\r8017990142064\r801792340068\r";

$varRep = str_replace('"', '', $var);
$varExp = explode('\r', $varRep);
```

Comment: É isto mesmo, obrigado pela ajuda, dentro de 5 minutos aceito a resposta!

Comment: Já passaram os 5 minutos...